# Bash script to run command with prompt for input

Tags: macos, bash, script

How can I create a script using the following command?

`mmap -sn -n x.x.x.x/8`, `/16`, `/24` and so on. I would like the script to run the command when I type in "sweep" and then prompt me for the subnet that I would like it to look on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! What have you tried so far? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

In your script you can put :

```
echo "Input subnet"
read subnet
```

to get user input and store it in a variable called subnet.

Obviously there is no check to see if you entered a valid subnet.